# In Perl, how can I print lines read from a file with optional leading whitespace removed?

Tags: regex, perl, file, string

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open(SARAN,"first.txt") or die "Can't Open: $!\n";
while($line=<SARAN>)
{ 
print "$line\n";
} 
close SARAN;
```

Hi,
In the above perl script, i need one functionality...
in first.txt, each line starts with some space in front..
I need to print the lines without space in front...
What to do.

thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous: Do you want to print the lines that do not start
with space(s) or print all the lines after removing any leading space(s)?

@codaddict showed how to do the latter. I will show how to do the former:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $SARAN, '<', "first.txt" 
    or die "Can't open 'first.txt': $!";

while (my $line = <$SARAN>) 
{ 
    print $line unless $line =~ /^\s/;
} 

close $SARAN;
```

Note the following:

- `use` [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) will help you catch
  programming errors.
- `use` [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) will alert you to
  dubious constructs.
- Bareword filehandles such as `SARAN` are package globals. Use lexical
  filehandles.
- Prefer the three-argument form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), especially if the filename is
  not hardcoded.
- Include the filename in the error message.
- Since you are not [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)ing
  `$line`, `print "$line\n"` would cause newlines to be doubled.

Comment: Slight pedantry. That regex can be simplified to /\s/ in this case. No need to look for more than one leading whitespace character.

Comment: @davorg Correct regarding the quantifier. However, the pattern still needs to be anchored.

Comment: Argh. Yes, I knew that. Would you believe it was a typo :-(

Answer (score 7):

you can do:

```
while($line=<SARAN>) { 
  $line=~s/^\s+//;  # delete the leading whitespace.
  print "$line\n";
}
```

We use the [**Perl's substitute operator**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) `s` which allows us to find a match using a regex and replace the part of the string that matched with another string.

Here we use the regex `^\s+`

- `^` is the start anchor.
- `\s` is any whitespace character.
- `+` quantifier to mark one or more

Basically we match and replace the leading one or more whitespace char with nothing which effectively means deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 open(SARAN,"first.txt") or die "Can't Open: $!\n";

 @line=< SARAN>;

 $str_line = join("", @line);

 print(SARAN "$str_line");

 close SARAN;
```